# One to Many Relationship Analysis Services

Tags: ssas, relationships

Our current relationship db environment is essentially a sku counting engine.  This makes pulling data through sql fairly easy but is causing me grief for developing a cube.  The problem I have is that any given sku can map to 1-4 different metrics (ie a mobile phone case will map to the Cases, Accessory, and Gross Profit metrics).  My question should I go about setting up my dimensions for this cube?

**Invoices**
InvoiceID
ProductID

**Metrics**
ProductID
MetricID

Thanks in advance for any incite that anyone can offer.

Comment: Should you set up dimensions?   Yes.   Did you mean to word that question differently somehow?

Comment: Yes sorry.  I meant to say how should I go about setting my dimensions.  I have a Product dimension but I am struggling with how to handle the multiple metrics for any given sku.

Comment: What is the struggle exactly?  Why can't you set up a simple star schema?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Invoices is one-to-one with Products.  Products is one-to-many with Metrics.  I'm running into 2 issues with hierarchies.  Starting with metrics, the values repeat.  When I try to put skus under a metric, I get a duplicate attribute error.  I apologize if I'm not stating things correctly.  I'm more accustomed to Oracle EPM so I'm a bit new here.

Comment: There isn't enough information to advise you here.   Sounds like you need to do some introductory tutorials on SSAS Database Modeling before you start on this.